# Message a single user by user id

Tags: python, botframework

I am looking at this sample: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/python/57.teams-conversation-bot/bots/teams_conversation_bot.py

_message_all_members iterates thorough a list of all members and sends each one a message.

I need a way to send one message to one user.  I know their user id.  Can you help me write a function that takes a text message and a user id and sends it.  Whoever wrote that sample is a pervert, and I can't unwrap all the layers. tc1, tc2.  wtf?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Nobody is just going to write custom code for you if you're not showing your own work and explain what you're not understanding.

Comment: I have tried saving the entire TurnContext and it works, but that is just doesn't seem right

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is "proactive notification", a method to send an activity to a user without the bot first receiving a message from them?

The thing that makes this awkward is that to use the SDK, you need to have a TurnContext that represents the conversation between the bot and the user... this is typically done using the `adapter.continue_conversation` method which requires you to pass the conversation reference. The conversation reference itself can either be cached from a previous bot message from that user or obtained by creating a new conversation with that user (this would be using the `adapter.create_conversation` method).

The `tc1`, `tc2` stuff are essentially just references to turn contexts in nested callback methods as this is how `create_conversation` and `continue_conversation` work.

There is a specific proactive notification sample that might work better for you here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/16.proactive-messages